# Combine Logical Operators

Tags: r, logical-operators

I'm quite new to R and I have a simple question I just can't figure out a simple problem. 
I want to combine two logical Statements  i.e. I want to exclude two Columns from my analysis
To exclude only one value the code works fine and looks like this:

`df[ colnames(df) != "Total.Population", function(x){ x/df$Total.Population *1000 }`

So besides the population I also want to exclude the column Geocodes from my analysis. I tried a lot of diffrent stuff like

`df[ colnames(df) != "Total.Population"&&"Geocodes", function(x){ x/df$Total.Population *1000 }`

but I just can't get it done to work for me...
so any help would be great. Thx

Comment: `&&` does not mean `AND AND` in the way you want. You are looking for `%in%` -- Your code is not reproducible at the moment.

Comment: You're missing a closing `]` and even beyond that your code makes no sense at the moment.  `function(x)` returns a function, not the value of that function.

Comment: It's just a small part of the code. So the whole Code looks like this:
`agriculture <-read.table ("C:\\Users\\etc….)
attach(agriculture)
df<-data.frame(agriculture)
df.per.capita <- as.data.frame(
 sapply(
  df[ colnames(df) != "Total.Population" %in% "Geocode"], function(x){ x/df$Total.Population *1000 }
  )
 ) 
detach(agriculture)
`

Comment: but the %in% dind't work either. There was no error warning but the two columns where processed anyway

Comment: You'd need to do `df[ !colnames(df) %in%c('name1','name2')]`

Comment: Allright. This one worked too. Nice and for a huge part of exclusions certainly a more elegant way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got no closing `]` . Please edit.   As to logical operators:  you want to select certain column indices, but you've "locked out" the comparson.  Do this:

```
 Rgames> foo
   one two three four five
1   1   5     9   13   17
2   2   6    10   14   18
3   3   7    11   15   19
4   4   8    12   16   20

Rgames> foo[ (colnames(foo) != "three")&(colnames(foo)!='two')]
one four five
1   1   13   17
2   2   14   18
3   3   15   19
4   4   16   20
```

Comment: all right. This one worked out! Thank's a lot for the explanation!